# google map on top of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Good morning!
I have the following problem:
I have a div that contains the main information on the web page (container) and a div that contains a Google Map. The user clicks a div and the Google Map is supposed to show up on top of container (hiding the web page). When I click the div, all I get is depicted in the image below.
http://prntscr.com/38ytlb
Notice that the map is correctly displayed on the screen (the Google logo on the lower left side and the Terms of Use on the lower right side). The map, however, takes only a small portion of the viewport.

```
<div id="container">
...
</div>
<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>

#map-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
}

#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#map-container").hide();

    $("#map-toggle").click(function () {
        $("#container").hide();
        $("#map-container").show();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We cannot debug code from an image. Please share your HTML / CSS / JS

Comment: `position:absolute;` and `z-index:999;` on Map

Answer (score 0):

You should check two things

1. That the map div is the right size
2. That you trigger resize on the map after you show it.  This will redraw the map and fix it's size to fill the div.

It should be something like this:

```
window.google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

`map` is whatever you named you google maps object.  All the samples on their site have it named `map`.

This would go right after:

```
$("#map-container").show();
```

Comment: tried it and still doesn't work. the pan doesn't work either (dragging to move the map). thanks for your time!